# How to span only the last record over two columns

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am using a sidewise table in which the last record need to span over two columns(merged). The MWC, observed output and the desired output is given below.

MWC

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}

\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.85in}
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.65in}
                             c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75in}
                             c
                             c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}
                             X}
\toprule
\thead{Reference}&\thead{Sensor\\type}&\thead{Sensor\\location}&\thead{No. of\\ sensors}&\thead{Processing\\location}&\thead{Method}&\thead{Accuracy\\in \%}&\thead{Features}&\thead{Limitations}\\
\midrule\\

[1]
  & Accelerometer, Gyroscope

    & External & $>1$ & On board & TB & Unknown
      & Fine grained fall detection with good accuracy.
        & No text based location, Fall and break of device aspect not considered.
\\
\addlinespace

[2]
  & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & 1 & On board and Remote
 & TB & Unknown
      &Fine grained fall detection with good accuracy. Reduced false alarm.
        &Device location in pocket of pant. No real life implementation case study. Fall and break aspect not considered.
\\
\addlinespace

[3]
  & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & $>1$ & On board and remote
 & ML & 91.83
      &Fall detection and ADL based on KNN classifier with accuracy  of 91.83\%
        &Store \& analyse, no live data, device fall is not considered. \\
\addlinespace

[4]
  &Camera
    & External & $>1$ & Remote
 & ML & Unknown
  & Image information is used for fall classification.
        &Slow, multiple image capturing device may be required, privacy issues.\\
\addlinespace

[5]
  & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & $>1$ & Remote
 & TB + ML & Unknown
      & Threshold analysis, reminder analysis and decision tree algorithm .
        & The non-functional aspect of the device after a fall is not considered.\\
\addlinespace

[6]
  & Pressure Sensor
    &Integrated in the operator's shoe & $>1$ & remote
 & TB & Unknown
      & Good result accuracy and can be implemented in IOT platform.
        & The nature of walking surface has a direct impact on accuracy.\\
\addlinespace

[7]
 & Accelerometer, Gyroscope
 &Smartphone in chest pocket & $>1$ & On board and remote
 & TB & Unknown
 & Smartphone Google API (location), Good accuracy.
 & Device location is not suitable for heart patient, Google API is not accurate in remote locations.\\
\addlinespace
[8]
 & MEMS tri-axis accelerometer
 &Upper trunk of the body & 1 & Remote
 & ML & Unknown
 & Fall detection and prediction using hidden Markov chain.
 & Location information as well as fall alike cases are not considered.\\
\addlinespace
[9]
 & UHF-RFID
 &Different locations inside the room & $>1$ & Remote
 &TB + ML & Unknown
 & Device and location independent fine grained fall detection.
 & Not suitable for outdoor monitoring.\\
\addlinespace
Proposed system
 & Smartphone accelerometer
 &Gender and garment independent, easy to wear phone holder & 1 & Remote
 &TB & Unknown
 & Text based location + SMS, Indoor and outdoor monitoring , Ineffectual device consideration, Non ambulatory, Non self-recovery warning only so number of warnings are less,  Simple fast and accurate.
 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

The observed output
[image: The observed output]
and
The Desired output
[image: Desired output(from MS word)]

Please help.

Comment: You can use `\multicolumn{2}{p{3.2in}}{...}` assuming you are ok with justified.  The 3.2in was obtained by trial and error.  It is possible to compute the precise width needed, but not easily.

Comment: Apart from the cell spanning two columns, the horizontal alignment in almost all column differs significantly when comparing the current and expected output. Do you also want to change that accordingly?

Comment: @leandris The MS word output is just to give an idea of what is expected, not to scale. BTW, the base table template is the one that you gave me in my other thread. I am using it for  every table successfully so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `tabular` and `multicolumn`..

[image: AR]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%   \usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\small

\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.60in}  % changed to tabular and first column
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.85in}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.95in} % increase width
        c
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.65in}
        c
        c
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}} %changed from X
    \toprule
    \thead{Reference}&\thead{Sensor\\type}&\thead{Sensor\\location}&\thead{No. of\\ sensors}&\thead{Processing\\location}&\thead{Method}&\thead{Accuracy\\in \%}&\thead{Features}&\thead{Limitations}\\
    \midrule\\
    
    [1]
    & Accelerometer, Gyroscope
    
    & External & $>1$ & On board & TB & Unknown
    & Fine grained fall detection with good accuracy.
    & No text based location, Fall and break of device aspect not considered.
    \\
    \addlinespace
    
    [2]
    & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & 1 & On board and Remote
    & TB & Unknown
    &Fine grained fall detection with good accuracy. Reduced false alarm.
    &Device location in pocket of pant. No real life implementation case study. Fall and break aspect not considered.
    \\
    \addlinespace
    
    [3]
    & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & $>1$ & On board and remote
    & ML & 91.83
    &Fall detection and ADL based on KNN classifier with accuracy  of 91.83\%
    &Store \& analyse, no live data, device fall is not considered. \\
    \addlinespace
    
    [4]
    &Camera
    & External & $>1$ & Remote
    & ML & Unknown
    & Image information is used for fall classification.
    &Slow, multiple image capturing device may be required, privacy issues.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [5]
    & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & $>1$ & Remote
    & TB + ML & Unknown
    & Threshold analysis, reminder analysis and decision tree algorithm .
    & The non-functional aspect of the device after a fall is not considered.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [6]
    & Pressure Sensor
    &Integrated in the operator's shoe & $>1$ & remote
    & TB & Unknown
    & Good result accuracy and can be implemented in IOT platform.
    & The nature of walking surface has a direct impact on accuracy.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [7]
    & Accelerometer, Gyroscope
    &Smartphone in chest pocket & $>1$ & On board and remote
    & TB & Unknown
    & Smartphone Google API (location), Good accuracy.
    & Device location is not suitable for heart patient, Google API is not accurate in remote locations.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [8]
    & MEMS tri-axis accelerometer
    &Upper trunk of the body & 1 & Remote
    & ML & Unknown
    & Fall detection and prediction using hidden Markov chain.
    & Location information as well as fall alike cases are not considered.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [9]
    & UHF-RFID
    &Different locations inside the room & $>1$ & Remote
    &TB + ML & Unknown
    & Device and location independent fine grained fall detection.
    & Not suitable for outdoor monitoring.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    Proposed system
    & Smartphone accelerometer
    &Gender and garment independent, easy to wear phone holder & 1 & Remote
    &TB & Unknown
    & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr1.5in+1.5in+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}}{% <<<< changed
        Text based location + SMS, Indoor and outdoor monitoring, Ineffectual device consideration, Non ambulatory, Non self-recovery warning only so number of warnings are less,  Simple fast and accurate.}
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

Not related to the question: I decreased the width of the first column and expanded the third to have less line breaks in that column.

UPDATE

The third column header might look a "little off center" while in fact is centered.

[image]

To get rid of this optical illusion replace  `\thead{Sensor\\location}` for `\bfseries Sensor location` in the header row and increase the width to allow for longer lines.

[image: W]

This is the final look and the complete code. You might use the same medicine to the header of the second column. (`\bfseries Sensor type`)

[image: F]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%   \usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\small

\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.60in}  % changed to tabular and first column
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.85in}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.1in} % increase width
        c
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.65in}
        c
        c
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}
        >{\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}} %changed from X
    \toprule
    \thead{Reference}&\thead{Sensor\\type}& \bfseries Sensor location&\thead{No. of\\ sensors}&\thead{Processing\\location}&\thead{Method}&\thead{Accuracy\\in \%}&\thead{Features}&\thead{Limitations}\\
    \midrule\\
    
    [1]
    & Accelerometer, Gyroscope
    
    & External & $>1$ & On board & TB & Unknown
    & Fine grained fall detection with good accuracy.
    & No text based location, Fall and break of device aspect not considered.
    \\
    \addlinespace
    
    [2]
    & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & 1 & On board and Remote
    & TB & Unknown
    &Fine grained fall detection with good accuracy. Reduced false alarm.
    &Device location in pocket of pant. No real life implementation case study. Fall and break aspect not considered.
    \\
    \addlinespace
    
    [3]
    & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & $>1$ & On board and remote
    & ML & 91.83
    &Fall detection and ADL based on KNN classifier with accuracy  of 91.83\%
    &Store \& analyse, no live data, device fall is not considered. \\
    \addlinespace
    
    [4]
    &Camera
    & External & $>1$ & Remote
    & ML & Unknown
    & Image information is used for fall classification.
    &Slow, multiple image capturing device may be required, privacy issues.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [5]
    & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & $>1$ & Remote
    & TB + ML & Unknown
    & Threshold analysis, reminder analysis and decision tree algorithm .
    & The non-functional aspect of the device after a fall is not considered.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [6]
    & Pressure Sensor
    &Integrated in the operator's shoe & $>1$ & remote
    & TB & Unknown
    & Good result accuracy and can be implemented in IOT platform.
    & The nature of walking surface has a direct impact on accuracy.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [7]
    & Accelerometer, Gyroscope
    &Smartphone in chest pocket & $>1$ & On board and remote
    & TB & Unknown
    & Smartphone Google API (location), Good accuracy.
    & Device location is not suitable for heart patient, Google API is not accurate in remote locations.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [8]
    & MEMS tri-axis accelerometer
    &Upper trunk of the body & 1 & Remote
    & ML & Unknown
    & Fall detection and prediction using hidden Markov chain.
    & Location information as well as fall alike cases are not considered.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    [9]
    & UHF-RFID
    &Different locations inside the room & $>1$ & Remote
    &TB + ML & Unknown
    & Device and location independent fine grained fall detection.
    & Not suitable for outdoor monitoring.\\
    \addlinespace
    
    Proposed system
    & Smartphone accelerometer
    &Gender and garment independent, easy to wear phone holder & 1 & Remote
    &TB & Unknown
    & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr1.5in+1.5in+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}}{% <<<< changed
        Text based location + SMS, Indoor and outdoor monitoring, Ineffectual device consideration, Non ambulatory, Non self-recovery warning only so number of warnings are less,  Simple fast and accurate.}
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document
```

Comment: The heading "Sensor location" has moved a bit right with respect to the corresponding column. Everything else is as expected. I tried to replace `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.95in} % increase width`   with 'c' but it is destroying the whole structure.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I am marking this as answer although a two liner like other headings would have been perfect. Anyway, it was beyond my beginner's knowledge to achieve even upto this. A heartful of thanks to you.

Comment: It might be done of course, but requires modifications of your code. I just tried to answer your original question. It is not the only one-line heading. Try to do it to the second column in the same way and will look even better.

Answer (score 2):

You can span using a modified X column

[image]

I did not have the class so the page size is a bit off but

```
 &\multicolumn{2}{X}{%
\hsize=\dimexpr\hsize+1.5in+2\tabcolsep\relax
```

does what you want here

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\advance\textheight 2in
\advance\textwidth 2in
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}

\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.85in}
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.65in}
                             c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75in}
                             c
                             c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}
                             X}
\toprule
\thead{Reference}&\thead{Sensor\\type}&\thead{Sensor\\location}&\thead{No. of\\ sensors}&\thead{Processing\\location}&\thead{Method}&\thead{Accuracy\\in \%}&\thead{Features}&\thead{Limitations}\\
\midrule\\
{[}1]
  & Accelerometer, Gyroscope

    & External & $>1$ & On board & TB & Unknown
      & Fine grained fall detection with good accuracy.
        & No text based location, Fall and break of device aspect not considered.
\\
\addlinespace

{[}2]
  & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & 1 & On board and Remote
 & TB & Unknown
      &Fine grained fall detection with good accuracy. Reduced false alarm.
        &Device location in pocket of pant. No real life implementation case study. Fall and break aspect not considered.
\\
\addlinespace

{[}3]
  & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & $>1$ & On board and remote
 & ML & 91.83
      &Fall detection and ADL based on KNN classifier with accuracy  of 91.83\%
        &Store \& analyse, no live data, device fall is not considered. \\
\addlinespace

{[}4]
  &Camera
    & External & $>1$ & Remote
 & ML & Unknown
  & Image information is used for fall classification.
        &Slow, multiple image capturing device may be required, privacy issues.\\
\addlinespace

{[}5]
  & Triaxial Accelerometer
    & External & $>1$ & Remote
 & TB + ML & Unknown
      & Threshold analysis, reminder analysis and decision tree algorithm .
        & The non-functional aspect of the device after a fall is not considered.\\
\addlinespace

{[}6]
  & Pressure Sensor
    &Integrated in the operator's shoe & $>1$ & remote
 & TB & Unknown
      & Good result accuracy and can be implemented in IOT platform.
        & The nature of walking surface has a direct impact on accuracy.\\
\addlinespace

{[}7]
 & Accelerometer, Gyroscope
 &Smartphone in chest pocket & $>1$ & On board and remote
 & TB & Unknown
 & Smartphone Google API (location), Good accuracy.
 & Device location is not suitable for heart patient, Google API is not accurate in remote locations.\\
\addlinespace
{[}8]
 & MEMS tri-axis accelerometer
 &Upper trunk of the body & 1 & Remote
 & ML & Unknown
 & Fall detection and prediction using hidden Markov chain.
 & Location information as well as fall alike cases are not considered.\\
\addlinespace
{[}9]
 & UHF-RFID
 &Different locations inside the room & $>1$ & Remote
 &TB + ML & Unknown
 & Device and location independent fine grained fall detection.
 & Not suitable for outdoor monitoring.\\
\addlinespace
Proposed system
 & Smartphone accelerometer
 &Gender and garment independent, easy to wear phone holder & 1 & Remote
 &TB & Unknown
 &\multicolumn{2}{X}{%
\hsize=\dimexpr\hsize+1.5in+2\tabcolsep\relax
 Text based location + SMS, Indoor and outdoor monitoring , Ineffectual device consideration, Non ambulatory, Non self-recovery warning only so number of warnings are less,  Simple fast and accurate.}
 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```